# Log4net - While application is running log alll steps in same file when day changes - do not create separete file

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, c#-3.0, log4net-configuration

I've console application that transfer bulk data, i've implemented logger functionality to log every steps of data transfer, it creates single file for each day to maintain the log of every transfer, but when process is running during mid night, and day changes a new file is created to continue with the execution of the process but the name includes the old date, for instance

2023-04-01-log-file.txt
2023-04-01-log-file.txt.2023-04-01

i searched many blogs but couldn't find perfect solution.

please find screenshot of my configuration in app.config.

[image]

my requirement is, when application is running & day get change, it should not create new file to log steps, it should continue logging details in same file.

can any one help me to update configuration.

looking forward to have a solution

Comment: Please don't post images as sources or dataset. You may take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people help you.